# Python: change directory to download folder in chrome os

Tags: python, google-chrome-os

I'm new to python and I can not figure out how to change the directory to the downloads folder in chrome OS. i have a `main.py` file i wanted to import.

i've tried

```
os.chdir("file:///home/chronos/user/downloads")

os.chdir("/home/chronos/user/downloads")
```

I can only get as far as `/home` and then it stops me. I wasnt sure if i had to be in developer mode or not to `chdir` past `/home`
can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

## What are you up to?

Chromebooks and Chromeboxes by default don't have Python, or a way to install it. That's kind of the point of Chrome OS. So a little info about your setup would be most helpful.

That said, Chrome OS *can be made to do* lots of useful things (such as... run Python scripts), but yes, *at minimum* you have to enable developer mode and install some things.

## Easiest possible answer:

Since I use [crouton](https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton) for all my Chromebook developer stuff, I'll answer with the assumption that you do too:

**From inside the chroot**, try `/home/[username]/Downloads` instead. This points to the same `Downloads` directory as the one you can see from within Chrome OS.